# How does Pinsker's inequality provide "a lower bound for the error of certain hypothesis testing problems"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Whilst flicking through *Concentration Inequalities: A Nonasymptotic Theory of Independence* by Boucheron, Lugosi and Massart (2016), I came across the following incidental remark:

> The importance of Pinsker's inequality in statistics stems from the fact that it provides a lower bound for the error of certain hypothesis testing problems.

The authors do not specify the hypothesis testing problems whose error can be lower bounded by [Pinsker's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinsker%27s_inequality), presumably because their focus in the book is not statistics. Nor do they specify how this might work. I would therefore greatly appreciate if members of the community could shed some light on the following question:

*What are the authors referring to when they say that the utility of Pinsker's inequality "stems from the fact that it provides a lower bound for the error of certain hypothesis testing problems? And how would this work?*

---

**Context.**

Here is an extract from *Section 4.11 Pinsker's inequality* of the monograph, where the remark can be found:

> Pinsker's inequality relates the relative entropy of two probability distributions to their variational distance. Let $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ be two probability measures on a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$. The *total variation* or *variational distance* between $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ is defined by
>
> $$V(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}) = \sup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \vert \mathcal{P}(A) - \mathcal{Q}(A) \vert.$$
> It is a well known and simple fact that the total variation is half the $L_1$-distance, that is if $\lambda$ is the common dominating measure of $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ and $p(x) = d\mathcal{P}/d\lambda$ and $q(x) = d \mathcal{Q} / d \lambda$ denote their respective densities, then
>
> $$V(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}) = \mathcal{P}(A^*) - \mathcal{Q}(A^*) = \frac{1}{2} \int \vert p(x) - q(x) \vert d \lambda(x),$$
> where $A^* = \{x: p(x) \geq q(x) \}$. We note that another important interpretation of the variational distance is related to the best coupling of the two measures
>
> $$V(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q}) = \min \mathcal{P} \{X \neq Y \},$$
> where the minimum is taken over all pairs of joint distributions for the random variables $(X, Y)$ whose marginal distributions are $X \sim \mathcal{P}$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{Q}$. (The proof of these well-known facts is left as Exercise 4.5).
>
> *The importance of Pinsker's inequality in statistics stems from the fact that it provides a lower bound for the error of certain hypothesis testing problems* [my emphasis]. We use Pinsker's inequality for a completely different purpose, namely for establishing a transportation cost inequality that may be used to prove concentration inequalities. The proof of Pinsker's inequality derives easily from Hoeffding's inequality via the transportation cost bound of Lemma 4.1.8:
>
> **Theorem 4.1.9** (Pinsker's inequality) Let $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{Q}$ be probability distributions on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ such that $\mathcal{Q} \ll \mathcal{P}$. Then
>
> $$V(\mathcal{P}, \mathcal{Q})^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} D(\mathcal{Q} || \mathcal{P}).$$
> [Proof omitted.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have two hypothesis - Null hypothesis and an Alternate hypothesis. Under the null hypothesis, your test statistic follows a distribution $P$, say  $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and under the alternate hypothesis, it follows a distribution $Q$, say $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$.

Now say you want to calculate the maximum probability of error (between type I and type II).  If type I error is when your test statistic falls in the region $A$ under Null Hypothesis, then type II error is when your test statistic falls in region $A^c$ under alternate hypothesis.

Note that $1 - V(P,Q) \leq P(A) + Q(A^c)$ for any $A$, by definition of Total variation distance. Hence, the errors can be bounded as follows:

$\begin{align} \max (P(A),Q(A^c)) \geq \frac{P(A)+Q\left(A^{c}\right)}{2} & \geq \frac{1}{2} (1 - V) \\ &  
\geq \frac{1}{2} (1-\sqrt{\frac{D}{2}})
\end{align}$

The first inequality follows from $\max(x,y) \geq \frac{x+y}{2}$ and the third one follows from Pinskers inequality. For standard distributions, there will be closed form expression to compute the KL-divergence $D$.